# Nuget: List of framework tags

Tags: nuget

When building a multi-framework package for Nuget you need to divide up the library by framework target. For example:

- .NET 4.0 \lib\net40
- Silverlight 4 \lib\sl40

Where can I find the complete list of framework tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Supporting_Multiple_.NET_Framework_Versions_and_Profiles

Though it's missing .net micro framework. I'll update the docs

Comment: Showing everything in a single table would help alot. The narrative text is great for explaining how the structure works but sucks for finding things quickly.

Comment: You should contribute to our docs ;). We'll definitely improve this.

Comment: That would require knowing how to actually use it, a bit of a chicken and an egg problem.